# Validating values using Settings API?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, security, options, settings-api

I'm using the Settings API to create options for plugin. Do I need to validate the input values for the security (for example stripslashes etc)? (I could not find that part in most of the tutorials). Here's what I'm doing:

```
<form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php
        settings_fields( 'sandbox_theme_display_options' );
        do_settings_sections( 'sandbox_theme_display_options' );
        submit_button();            
    ?>
</form> 

function sandbox_initialize_theme_options() {
    add_settings_section(
        'general_settings_section',         
        __( 'Display Options', 'sandbox' ),
        'sandbox_general_options_callback',
        'sandbox_theme_display_options'
    );

    add_settings_field( 
        'show_header',
        __( 'Header', 'sandbox' ),
        'sandbox_toggle_header_callback',
        'sandbox_theme_display_options',
        'general_settings_section',
        array(
            __( 'Activate this setting to display the header.', 'sandbox' ),
        )
    );

register_setting(
        'sandbox_theme_display_options',
        'sandbox_theme_display_options'
    );

}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'sandbox_initialize_theme_options' );
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to validate/clean/escape because of security flaws in wordpress. Wordpress use [prepared statements](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) by default.

However, you can validate by yourself that the content is what you expecting. For example if you only want numbers you can use `is_numeric()` or `is_float()`. Or match the input value to an array of predefined strings.